# C# MVC routing issue with same parameter same controller action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "PNM",
           url: "PNM/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "DTE",
           url: "DTE/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "CE",
           url: "CE/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

I have routes configured like this. When I run the web site I get this url localhost:12345/

and then I can type any client name to get the client specific logo
localhost:12345/CE which takes me to the login page with CE logo.

Here's the issue : Once I login URL gets changed to http://localhost:12345/PNM/Home/Index

while I am in CE url should be http://localhost:12345/CE/Home/Index

How should I write my routeconfig file? or what should I change that it goes to specific-client url all the time when I navigate to any page in the website?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a single route and move the client name as a parameter?

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{clientName}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", clientName = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

This approach is more dynamic than specifying different routes for each client. I haven't tested this yet, just trying to give you a different approach.